# (Qt) Losing contact with items added to an scene. Cannot get positions

Tags: c++, qt, view, scene

I'm trying to set up a configuring widget for an editable structure form  widget so that the positions of the "to be filled LineEdits" are chose arbitrary by the user.

My idea is to gather the wanted positions of the LineEdits by using a widget made of a QGraphicsScene scene, a QGraphicsView view, and some references to the LineEdits items with proper name: QTextItems.

I have managed to add the reference items to the scene, have shown the view and have been able to put the items on the positions I wanted. The problem is once the items are added to the scene, I lose all contact with them and I can't know which item is in which position.
Here is a little example:

```
scene = new QGraphicsScene(myWidgetSize_QRect);
view = new QGraphicsView(scene);
view->setAcceptDrops(true);


for(int i=0, i<number_of_input_fields, i++)
{
    GraphicsTextItem *item=new GraphicsTextItem();
    //Configure Item
    item->setFlags(QGraphicsItem::ItemIsMovable|QGraphicsItem::ItemIsSelectable);
    item->setAcceptedMouseButtons(Qt::LeftButton);
    item->setAcceptDrops(true);
    item->setCursor(Qt::OpenHandCursor);

    QString txt("");

    txt = textForItem(i);//some function that defines the text. 
                         //Suppose it have returned for some items: "Name", "Address"

    item->setPos(20+20*i,20+20*i);//load the items on different positions
    scene->addItem(item);
}


view->show();
```

Well, having done a code alike I don't know how to get the positions back once they were moved to the desired location.
Let me be more specific if I have placed the items with the text "Name" and "Adress" on the positions I wanted, I don't know how to get the position of the "Name" item.

The only access I have to the items after adding them to the scene is:

```
scene->items();
```

I don't how the items on that list are ordered. And don't know how to know which is which...

I'm having a very hard time doing this, I have been putting off this while concentrating in some other things... but I have reached the time I cannot continue coding other things because this is a main feature of my program

Any help will be very appreciated... Thank you.

Comment: The code your provided is quite missleading, since we don't have a clue what `j` is. Also - if you set the positions manually, can't you just store them somewhere or calculate once more when needed? You don't change them anywhere else.

Comment: Pawel, it was a mistake it was "i" instead of "j".
The problem is unless I make a step by step solution, setting a LineEdit position each time, I couldn't know which item the position belongs to.

Comment: And mainly I don't know what function should I call to get the position even if I tried to do what I told you above.
Because, for example, don't know how to convert a item->pos to a widget referenced position. And I have not understood the documentation on this.